# Can PHP and Oracle pass complex types to each other?

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, oci8

I want to pass/bind an array of (key1, key2) to an Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure using PHP.  I'm able to bind primitive types and arrays of primitive types, but haven't found a way to pass complex datatypes back and forth.

Is this unsupported?  So far I've been having to pass along multiple arrays -- one for each subtype in my complex type -- and then depend on their indexes to reconstitute them in the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why don't you serialize the object's state as XML?**

Currently it's pretty common practice to searilize objects as XML so they can be passed across the web in a language/platform agnostic manner. Why not do the same and store it as a varchar in the DB.

*Note: The glaring deficiency of this method is you won't be able to select fields in the database by attributes of the object in a clean manner because it mixes multiple attributes of the object in one field of the database.*

If you *do* need the attributes of the object to be searchable, you'll need to break out the data from each of the object's attributes into their own respective fields.

Comment: This is a good idea given the apparent lack of support in PHP/OCI8 for passing complex data types.  I think I may use XML as the language for passing data to my procedures, but will parse it in the procedure and treat it after that point as if it arrived in that format (rather than directly inserting the XML into the table).

Answer (score 3):

Does not seem supported. `oci_bind_array_by_name()` and `oci_bind_by_name()` seems to only be able to pass primitive types. The [documentation](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.oci-bind-array-by-name.php) does not show any other possibility.

Sharing object/structures/complex types is not easy, as the representation of an object in different languages can be far from each other. For example `memcached` allow to store objects from any language that has a library that convert objects from its own representation to memcached one and vice versa.

You could do it if oci8 had a converter between PHP hashes/objects to complex types in PL/SQL but that's not the case.

You just can make several calls to `oci_bind_by_name()` and so call your procedure with as many arguments as needed for each key of your hash/complex type.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Evans's suggestion, I'd recommend using JSON. Both [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [Oracle](http://database-geek.com/2009/03/25/json-in-and-out-of-oracle-json-data-type/) can encode/decode JSON and it's substantially less verbose than XML.

Whichever you go for, serialization is probably the way to go. That said, I would advise against storing the raw JSON in a varchar field - Oracle is able (with the tool linked above) to both interpret JSON and generate JSON responses.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is "lighter" but I'm really unclear as to why would anyone want to use JSON in Oracle with the power of Oracle XML handling capabilities and XML DB at one's disposal. The serialisation discussion disappears as Oracle can "shred" XML into relational tables for high performance and accessibility without the developer writing a single line of code (and also without having to rely on unproven json projects) - and likewise retrieve it as XML transparently.

Another observation is that to remain "database agnostic" as recommended above, while portable, dramaticly limits the developer's ability to take advantage of the massively powerful features that today's database engines provide.

I'm aware that this commentary is "late" however these statements all held true in Oracle 10g at the time of the answers above and I'm sure people still face this particular challenge

My strong recommendation for all out there using PHP and Oracle is use XML and take advantage of Oracles incredible XML handling features.